# Windows default gateway is showing on-link

Tags: networking, windows-8, routing

I'm using 3G mobile to connect to the Internet on my Windows 8 machine. I'm connecting directly to 3G, not through a router.

Here is the screenshot of my routing table:

[image]

Why is the default gateway showing `on-link`?

From what I know, "on-link" means that it is directly reachable. How is this possible?

Shouldn't there be some IP address as the gateway for the default route?

Comment: What's your IP address?

Comment: @cpast 115.247.74.119  it's a dynamic ip .

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.  Because a 3G mobile dongle is effectively a modem rather than a router.  Your connection to it is not routed, it is layer 2.

Any packets that aren't destined for your local network are handed off to the 3G dongle, where they are transported at layer 2 to the gateway.  After that they are routed, but this is not done by your machine.

Comment: thanks. Please can you elaborate this ? any article link on this topic would be great help . :)

Comment: @Torpido Yeah, I have been trying to come up with a better description, but it is difficult without some foundation knowledge.  Perhaps come into chat and see if we can work out a better answer: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: ok do I have to post question there ?